# Set filename of package generated by maven

Tags: spring, maven

I've got a `pom.xml` file which builds an Java Spring artifact to a war-file.
The war-file-name for the example below is always `artifact 1.0.war`

I want it to be just artifact.war because I need to deploy it to a Tomcat server where all url-configurations are overwritten.

How can I remove the version from the package file-name?

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>MyArtifact</name>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can give in the build section:

```
<build>
  ..
 <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
  ..
</build>
```

Or just change the context path in the web.xml (or may be in tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of Maven, you should use `project.` prefix in order to access `pom.xml` properties. It would look as:

```xml
<build>
  ...
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
  ...
</build>
```